# Extjs incorrect sorting at grouping grid

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Mb, anybody know, why features incorrect grouped sorted data at grid?
Example:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fg4

P.S. I  grouped on the field 'proejct', 'projectId', but all to no avail.
I wanna next result:

```
    | 1. blablabla | 
    | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
    | 2. blablabla |
    | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
    .......
    | 10. blablabla |
    | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
    | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |    
    | 11. blablabla |
    | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
    | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting numbers in strings will always yield this result. That is because a stringsort always look for the

- first char and sort by it,
- then he took the second and make a subsort
- then the third.... and so on

So the sorting is absolutely right. You should use a extra project number field as `int` / `number`, in your case `projectId`,  and group by it, that would solve your problem.

**Edit**

There is a bug in the ExtJS 5.0 release. It work in ExtJS 5.1

See this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fg6)

Now to the changes:

You need to group by

```
groupField: 'projectId'
```

the sorter is not required because grouping will sort

and to display the the project field use the following group-header-template

```
groupHeaderTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
    '{children:this.format}',
    {
        format: function(c) {
            return c[0].get('project');
        }
    }
)
```